# Filter the values in a flat array using a regular expression

Tags: php, arrays, regex, filtering, preg-grep

I have an array of words and an array of stopwords. I want to remove those words from the array of words that are in the stopwords array, but the code returns all words:

```
function stopwords($x){
      return !preg_match("/^(.|a|car|red|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to)$/",$x);
    };

$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, "stopwords");
```

Why?

Comment: [Working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mxhGZE) fine for me.

Comment: Make sure that the words in the array don't have any whitespace characters at the beginning or end of each word, so that "red" really is `"red"` and not `"red "`: note that whitespace characters could include newlines or other invisible characters, so check the actual length

Comment: I think `$wordArray` is not an array maybe (in your condition). What error does it show when i runs. It works fine for us.

Comment: My bad, thanks for checking it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$wordArray = ["hello","red","world","is"];

function stopwords($x){
      return !preg_match("/^(.|a|car|red|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to)$/",$x);
    };

$filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, "stopwords");
var_dump($filteredArray);

# results out:
array(2) {
   [0] =>   string(5) "hello"   
   [2] =>   string(5) "world"
}
```

What do you think it was going to return?

Is your input '$wordArray' a string, or an array?

Comment: Although it was my fault and the code was ok, I accept this solution for providing an example

Answer (score 0):

> // Should be an Array 
>    $wordArray = array('he', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'bed' );
>
> // Should return boolean 
>   function stopwords ($x) 
>   { 
>        return !preg_match("/^(.|a|car|red|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to)$/",$x); 
>   } 
>   
>   //filter array
>   $filter = array_filter($wordArray, "stopwords");
>   
>   // Output 
>   echo "< pre>"; 
>   print_r($filter);
>
> // Result 
>   Array 
>   ( 
>           [0] => he 
>           [2] => going 
>           [4] => bed 
>   )

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    $words = array('apple','boll','cat','dog','elephant','got');
        $stopwords = array('cat','apple');

       foreach($words as $k=>$v)
        {
        if(in_array($v,$stopwords)){
            unset($words[$k]);  
        }

      }
print_r($words);
```